# Deleting a line from the one2many field with constraint on unique sequence

Tags: python, odoo

I created an object "scanning.invoice.approval.rule", in which I defined a one2many field:

```
approval_line_ids = fields.One2many(
    'scanning.invoice.approval.line', 'rule_id', string='Approval Lines')
```

this line object is defined as such:

```
class InvoiceApprovalRuleLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'scanning.invoice.approval.line' 
    _order = 'sequence ASC'

    rule_id = fields.Many2one(
        'scanning.invoice.approval.rule', 'Approval Rule', required=True, ondelete='cascade') 
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'User', ondelete='cascade')
    sequence = fields.Integer()

    @api.multi
    @api.constrains('sequence')
    def _validate_sequence(self): 
        for rec in self:
            for line in rec.rule_id.approval_line_ids:
                if line == rec:
                    continue
                if line.sequence == rec.sequence:
                    raise ValidationError(_('Multiple Roles with sequence %s exist') % rec.sequence)
```

the problem is when I add a rule and lines and save, then edit again, remove one line with sequence 1 for example, then add new line with same sequence 1 as the deleted line then save, the constrains is raised despite I just removed one line and added another with the same sequence, I hope this is clear, and thank a lot for all your help

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: edit the role the form view, then remove one of the role lines from the trash icon at the end of the line (standard odoo) , then create a new line with the same sequence of the deleted line then save, the constrains is launched despite that the is no real duplicate sequence for that role (I think the constrains function is launched before the write of the role that delete the line)

Comment: @api.multi
    @api.constrains('sequence')
    def _validate_sequence(self):
        # Ensure there is no other line with the same sequence
        for rec in self:
            for line in rec.rule_id.approval_line_ids:
                if line == rec:
                    continue
                if line.sequence == rec.sequence:
                    raise ValidationError(_('Multiple Roles with sequence %s exist') % rec.sequence)

Comment: @Ibtissem Have you tried doing the same with SQL constraint.

Comment: @MihranThalhath same thing my friend :(

Comment: did you try my answer?!! It worked for me